# MongoDB "Unrecognized option: net.ssl.PEMKeyFile"

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB v3.0.0 with the following configuration file:

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/home/vagrant/backend/mongodata"
   engine: wiredTiger

systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/home/vagrant/backend/log/mongo.log"
   logAppend: true

net:
   port: 27017
   # Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
   http:
      enabled: false
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /home/vagrant/backend/keys/privKeys.pem

security:
   authorization: 'enabled'
```

But when I start it up, I get the following error:

`Unrecognized option: net.ssl.PEMKeyFile
try '/home/vagrant/backend/mongo/bin/mongod --help' for more information`

It looks like I have it set up pretty much exactly like they recommend in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/ . The docs say this is new in mongo 3.0, so it should support this option. It does say certain distributions still don't support it (bizarrely), so I should include that I installed mongo via this: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.0.tgz . The closest info I could find is the MongoDB Download Center saying version 3.0.14 for linux "has been compiled with SSL enabled and dynamically linked. This requires that SSL libraries be installed seperately. See here for more information on installing OpenSSL."

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, looks like maybe this package doesn't support ssl after all.. Looks like my package is what they call "Linux 64-bit legacy x64"

Answer (score 3):

For me its looks like spacing issue in configuration you may need to check the spacing only two spaces are allowed with list members ssl become underneath of net so when declaring ssl ensure the spaces

here are my working configurations.

```
net:
  port: 28017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/mongodb-server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/mongodb-client.pem
    PEMKeyPassword: abc123+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB v3.0.x *most* MongoDB distributions include support for SSL, but not all. As you have figured out, most likely the distribution that you have does not support SSL.

If you're starting a new MongoDB deployment, I would recommend to install the latest stable release, currently at [MongoDB v3.4.x](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community) which have more (if not all) distributions supporting SSL. See [Release Notes for MongoDB 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/)

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me Mongo version 4.2.8 :**

**Ignore the message** *and check the Mongo logs, I found that the path configured for the PEM file was incorrect and should be the fully qualified path. Even after configuring it right, there was this SSL warning that was still present but worked.*

```
ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: /data/users/mongodb/mongodb.pem
        PEMKeyPassword: YOUR_PASS
```